# Why do two Android screens with exactly the same (relevant) code, show a different action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, back

I've got two screens in my android app in which I want to show virtually the same actionbar: a title on the left which functions as a back button (the usual way) and an "OK"-icon on the right to submit the information on the page.

The screens both have the same relevant "backbutton code":

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

But somehow, one of the screens shows the title as a backbutton, while the other one only shows the title without it being a backbutton.

I must be forgetting something somewhere, but I've been overlooking the code over and over again and I'm going nuts because I can't find the mistake I'm making.

Does anybody have a tip as to what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: This isn't really enough code to make any statements.  can you provide more code?

Comment: I would check how each is styled in the manifest. Also, if you can post screencaps that would help because I can't really visualize what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have defined which Activity is 'parent' in your manifest. You must do this for every Activity because the Up navigation is defined differently to Back navigation.

android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"

See: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest. If you declare an activity as having a parent with

```
android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
```

then Android will by default enable Up navigation in the ActionBar, which it looks like it is doing.